# Why does this recursive code throw a segfault?

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault

When I run the following code compiled with with `gcc` (only option turned on is `-std=c99`) and run the executable, I get a segmentation fault (msg core dumped).

Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count_factors(int n, int i) {
    int m = n;
    if (m == i) {
        return 1;
    } else if (m % i == 0) {
        while (m % i == 0) m = m / i;
        return 1 + count_factors(m, i);
    } else {
        return count_factors(m, i+1);
    }
}

int main() {

    int streak_size = 4;
    int streak = 0;
    int solution = 0;
    int n = 2;

    while (solution == 0) {
        n += 1;
        int c = count_factors(n, 2);
        if (c == streak_size) {                  
            streak += 1;
        } else {
            streak = 0;
        }
        if (streak == streak_size) solution = n;
    }
    printf("%i", solution);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you never get out of your recursion in `count_factors`. Put `printf("%d %d\n", n, i);` at the beginning of `count_factors` and you'll understand.

Comment: Oh the irony, on a site called 'StackOverflow'.

Comment: You should always enable warnings when compiling, for example `-Wall`.  Note that this is general advice and may not help solve your particular issue.

Comment: Of course, runaway recursion coud not be detected by trivial debugging... :((

Comment: Hi, I suppose detecting infinite recursion bugs like this one falls on the halting problem so it couldn't be possibly detected by the compiler? Or am I exaggerating?

Answer (score 2):

In your recursion, there's one base case you're considering.  However, there are two:

- `m == i`: This occurs when there is only 1 of the largest factor
- `m == 1`: This happens when there are multiple of the largest factor

You're going into an infinite loop on `m=4` and `n=2` because you're missing the second case.  Here, `if (m % i == 0)` is true, so  `while (m % i == 0) m = m / i;` runs.  And since 4 is a multiple of 2, this loop will end when `m` is 1.

When you recurse again, you have `m=1` and `n=2`.  This will hit the `else` clause, where you call `count_factors` again with `m=1` and `n=3`.  This keeps going until the stack blows up.

Adding the second base case will fix the infinite recursion:

```
int count_factors(int n, int i) {
    int m = n;
    if (m == i) {
        return 1;
    } else if (m == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else if (m % i == 0) {
        while (m % i == 0) m = m / i;
        return 1 + count_factors(m, i);
    } else {
        return count_factors(m, i+1);
    }
}
```

Actually, you can get rid of the first case, since it's just a special case of `if (m % i == 0)`:

```
int count_factors(int n, int i) {
    int m = n;
    if (m == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else if (m % i == 0) {
        while (m % i == 0) m = m / i;
        return 1 + count_factors(m, i);
    } else {
        return count_factors(m, i+1);
    }
}
```

The program then runs to completion, outputting 134046.

EDIT:

It will run faster without recursion:

```
int count_factors(int n, int i) {
    int m = n;
    int total = 0;
    while (m != 1) {
        if (m % i == 0) {
            while (m % i == 0) m = m / i;
            total++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return total;
}
```

On my machine, the recursive version takes about 9 seconds.  The iterative version takes about 3 seconds.